# ACF on parts of dataset?

Tags: r

R noob here, I am running acf's In R to check Auto-correlation on my data before running other tests. 
Now I am running into 2 problems. I have time-series data for 26 years (1990-2016).

**Problem 1**. For some of my variables a couple of years have missing data (1995-1997). For these specific variables I would like to start the acf at the year 1998. Is this possible?

**Problem 2**. One variable has multiple years with missing data throughout the time-series, but only for odd years. Is it possible to do an acf for only even years?

I could manually adjust the data but would prefer to keep it as one dataset.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please have a look a look at this post on how to make a reproducible example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes, of course this is possible. Just subset your time series. But I think you should first have a discussion with a statistician.